# JPA rollback not working in Tomcat but working in JBOSS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have created a Spring(4.0.2) + JPA/hibernate(4.3.4) project. I am trying to test its commit and rollback. In my service layer while testing for rollback, i am trying to have a transaction where save first object then throw error and save second object,....in jboss its working as expected where even first object is not saved in DB but in tomcat its saving first object even though error is thrown in service method...my sample code is below

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pkg.*" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS" />
 <!-- <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/jBPMDS" /> -->

 <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mainPU"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
     </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <!-- <property name="database" value="ORACLE" /> -->
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
     <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

my service class

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void addPersonException() throws Exception{
        try{
        Person p=new Person();
        p.setAge(20);
        p.setFirstName("Exception 1");
        p.setLastName("Exception Last Name 1");

        commonDao.insert(p);
        String x=null;
        System.out.println(x.indexOf("1"));
        Person p2=new Person();
        p2.setAge(20);
        p2.setFirstName("Exception 2");
        p2.setLastName("Exception Last Name 2");

        commonDao.insert(p2);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("rollback added");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

CommonDao

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public  boolean insert(Object o){
        em.persist(o);

     }
```

Any idea why this is not working in tomcat?
Do i need to use JTA for tomcat?

Comment: I found a blog post describing your problem. Maybe this helps: http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/spring-3-hibernate-jpa-tomcat-transactions/

Comment: didnt work for me :( thnx anyways..

Comment: am i missing any configuration....as for jboss it works perfectly fine...but not on tomcat

Comment: tried with atomikos jta as well but still no rollback for first value saved :(